# Events not firing with UA and GTM - event equals gtm.js condition is not matched

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I've setup a Wordpress log and am using Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics. I'm trying to track a bunch of events - all of which are outbound links. I've setup the link listener and the event code itself within GTM and tested it on github. However when I push it to the live site the events don't fire. I can track pageviews fine but the events are not being captured.

I've debugged it as best I can and what I can see is that they're not firing because not all the conditions are being met. Specifically for some reason the gtm.js is not being pushed to the data layer.

Have included images of my setup. The site is http://notthatsamfox.com

Rule setup:
[image: Rule setup:]

Event tracking setup:
[image: event setup:]

Message pushed to data layer on click:
[image: data layer:]

Firing rules:
[image: data layer:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a look at your source code, and noticed that the GTM container is at the bottom, just before your closing body tag. The container should be placed just after the **opening** body tag, and not at the end. Try that and see if you get any results.

Quickly glancing at your setup, everything looks good.

Comment: Thanks for reply nyuen. Not sure how that happened. I've fixed that but still same issue present. Here's the debug info for the outbound links if that's any help http://i.imgur.com/Plj6ZuX.png

Comment: Hi, Fox87, can you try removing the "_event equals gtm.js" rule and see if your outbound link event fires?

Comment: Hey nyuen, that's a rule that is automatically appended. It's not a rule I manually configured. Not sure why it's there since it should only be there if there were no other rules in place

Comment: Hi Fox87 (sorry for delayed response). Are you still having the same problem? I was able to go to your site and test the GTM event for myself (injected my own GTM container). I configured it the same as what you have above, and the Outbound link event successfully fired.

Comment: No worries. Yeah I was. I reverted back to standard GA as I couldn't figure it out. Interesting that you got it working. I'm not sure what would cause the different behavior? I assume I must be missing something but not sure what..

Comment: I've reverted it back to GTM. Removed the event links, admittedly only on this page: http://www.notthatsamfox.com/2014/07/12/journey-start/

but still don't see it firing

Comment: I can't attach screenshots of what I did, but I just started a brand new GTM container, created the gtm.linkClick tag to fire on every page, created the Outbound event to fire when {{event}} equals gtm.linkClick, and {{element url}} does not contain notthatsamfox. The Outbound event has category="Outbound", action="Learn more", label={{element url}}.

Comment: Great work! Glad to hear you've got it working, and glad to be of service!

Comment: How did you get it working? Please fix the answer or add an answer of your own @Fox87. Simple page triggers are all that I can use to trigger a tag on "some pages" but this trigger adds this extra rule on `_event`, and when this is coupled with tag sequencing, it doesnt work..

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may have already solved your problem but for anyone else who is finding that gtm.js appears not to be firing, check to make sure that your dataLayer initialization,

`datalayer = [{"stuff":"here"}]`

is above the Google Tag Manager Container:

```
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  ...
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>
    dataLayer = [{
      'pageCategory': 'signup',
      'visitorType': 'high-value'
    }];
```

Otherwise, initializing the dataLayer below the container will overwrite the GTM dataLayer. The docs on this are here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#datalayer

Comment: This was helpful. Maybe we should open similar question.

Comment: Additionally, check the implementation of the actual snippet, and that it matches exactly to either what GTM recommends at the time or at least the format in an environment where it's working. I've just spent a day chasing my tail to find that someone had missed two pairs of "[]" in the initalising of the dataLayer, meaning the .push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'}) wasn't working, and therefore no gtm.js Page View event. I should've noticed when I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

Use at the rule, the firing event gtm.dom.

{{event}} equals gtm.dom

Comment: It would be great if you can elaborate a bit.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution as the gtm.js event should be firing as part of implementation of the GTM snippet. Using a different event as a trigger is just fixing a symptom and not the cause. For anyone who reads this, he means to create a trigger where instead of using the Page View event, it's using Dom Load or Window Loaded, which are two more options in the trigger configuration. This will work but ultimately you should investigate and solve the problem at source. It's probably an incorrect implementation.