# Google Tag Manager _event macro

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up Google Tag Manager. To keep it simple I created a click event tag that fires on all pages. When I get I see that the event fires on page load. However, it and all other tags I've tried fail because of not matching the rule '_event equals gtm.js'. I did not make this rule. I found this SO question [Events not firing with UA and GTM - event equals gtm.js condition is not matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581005/events-not-firing-with-ua-and-gtm-event-equals-gtm-js-condition-is-not-matched) but the solution of creating a new container did not work for me.

Anyone know where this _event macro is and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will preface with this with: I'm not exactly sure this is right because I have no real proof other than the behavior I see.

If you don't give the rule an event condition it defaults to '_event equals gtm.js'. So it only passes the condition when the GTM script is loaded. Adding an event rule condition seems to keep GTM from adding the _event condition.

Answer (score 1):

"Event" is a reserved word / macro name in Google Tag Manager. An GTM event (not to be confused with a javascript event or and Google Analytics event) can be used to trigger tags. At several occasions - tag manager script is loaded (gtm.js), DOM ready (gtm.dom) etc - the event variable is automatically populated.

If you have indeed an underscore in the name ("_event" instead of "event") your rule fails because _event is (due to the underscore) not the special word GTM is looking for.

You cannot (and should not) get rid of event macros.

Comment: How does the "_event" macro get created in the first place?

Comment: How it gets added to my tag was really my main concern. It appears that if you don't add an event then your tag gets the _event rule added. I don't absolutely know this for sure but it's the behavior I see.

Answer (score 0):

I changed "**Trigger type**" from the default "**Page view**" to "**Custom event**" and set my custom Event name. It worked for me